# virtualenv doesn't work on network drive on other computers

Tags: python, django, batch-file, virtualenv

I set up virtualenv on network drive using virtualenv python module. It generated me few folders: Include, Lib, Scripts, share, tcl. Inside the folder with these folders i created new one called scr and then pasted there a django app called vistool. Now i created two batch scripts, to allow other users of network drive to run this app:

run.bat (main file):

```
cd /d "Z:\xx\Tools\New\Widget - Graphs"
cd visual\Scripts
start server.bat
timeout 30
start http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphtool/
```

This one seems to work, as it does everything it should.
The other one that is called inside run.bat is server.bat, which i placed in Scripts(the same folder where activate.bat is.

server.bat (for calling activate.bat and django built-in server):

```
call activate.bat
cd..
cd src/vistool
call python manage.py runserver
```

Now, these two scripts are working fine for me and they do what they want - open a tab with a django project in the browser. But on other computers in my company this doens't work and I have no idea why. Activate.bat from virtualenv package takes the

```
set "VIRTUAL_ENV=Z:\xxx\Tools\New\Widget - Graphs\visual"
```

Which should be ok, since everyone has got mapped this network disc the same. The errors that they get are: "Could not find django". Even if i set up my env correctly and installed all the packages I use in it. And the activate.bat seems to work for them. It looks like the virtualenv can't see installed packages? But then why is it working for me? 
Edit: When I try to install something on Their computers I get an error, that I don't have runpy installed. When I try to pip install runpy I still can't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocating virtual environment project from local to server (flask project), have to install dependencies again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225853/relocating-virtual-environment-project-from-local-to-server-flask-project-hav)

Comment: Virtual environments are not portable across machines!