# Python virtualenv copy to another machine?

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, virtualenvwrapper, distribute

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04

I made a virtualenv in one project in computer A, and I moved the project to computer B.

The paths where the project is placed are different. It does not work with computer B.

> Computer A's project path: /home/projects/projectA
>
> Computer B's project path: /home/sv_projects/projectA

It seems like the source tries to look for the original path. It does not show any path if I do 'which python' after source the virtualenv.

To do the cross checking, I made a copy of the project A in computer A and do 'which python' after source the virtualenv.

> which python
>
> /home/projects/projectA/venv/bin/python

where I expect it to be

> /home/projects/projectA_copy/venv/bin/python

Because I think if it changes to print as what I expected, I can apply it to the computer B with the exactly same way.

''' added '''

.

After digging around, I found out that the path can be changeable only and if the the virtualenv installed in computer B with options of --extra-search-dir. But this is not what I want, since it depends on the library; meaning I need virtualenv every time I want to copy the environment to a new machine.

**I would like to know HOW TO COPY the virtualenv environment to another machine!**

So the question is...
How can I change the path of the sourced virtualenv python?
Or how can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the error you get?
Are you activating the virtualenv?
Are you using relative paths in your script?

Comment: It doesn't occur any error. It just does not work as I expected. I thought it would be working if I copy the project from one computer to another.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot, or let's say the efforts needed to achieve this is much higher than the advantages. So just create another venv on computer B and `pip -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocating virtual environment project from local to server (flask project), have to install dependencies again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225853/relocating-virtual-environment-project-from-local-to-server-flask-project-hav)

Comment: Yes I can. I searched through internet and even stackoverflow recommends to fix the venv/bin/activate file. It works in my local computer A but it does not work with the computer B, so I posted this question up in here.

Comment: phd, the link you gave me is a bit different. .   think about my question as 'how to make python project a distribution version?'

Comment: `virtualenv` is only for development, not for distribution/deployment. Use eggs, wheels, freeze using `py2exe` or `PyInstaller`.

Comment: phd can you explain more details about it?

Comment: phd // I took a look what you recommended and it seems like they're making distributional files for windows. Do you know any other methods for linux (especially ubuntu) ?